# How to click a <a> tag in phantomjs 2.0.0?

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs

There is a onclick function tied up with this  tag. I need to trigger this onclick function, so I used

```
page.sendEvent('click', element.offsetLeft, element.offsetTop, 'left');
```

But it seems not working. How to make a click on  tag? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You haven't shown us your complete code. Are you sure that `element` contains your element? Perhaps you're executing `page.sendEvent()` inside of the page context which is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include jquery by doing

```
page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', callback_function);
```

More info: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html

and then use jQuery and do from the callback function

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    $('#mylink').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for correcting me. I have updated the code above.